# HEALTHCHECK in ECS Container

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I'm struggling setting up the correct HEALTHCHECK for a Container inside Task Definition in Amazon ECS.

I've tried multiple solutions and can't get the simplest "always true" healthcheck to actually work.

My Healthcheck looks like this:

```
[ "CMD-SHELL", "echo"]
```

which to my understanding should always produce a healthy container but unfortunately I always get an UNHEALTHY status.
When I do a docker inspect on the unhealthy container I get the following

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-77 ~]$ docker inspect 8f14979ae4eb
[
    {
        "Id": "8f14979ae4eb4e16ec26a4ac886d29b29f5666e5f00d41c56d25f5efe0c7d57e",
        "Created": "2018-05-15T08:55:50.399791936Z",
        "Path": "/bin/sh",
        "Args": [
            "-c",
            "echo \"The application will start in ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}s...\" &&     sleep ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP} &&     java ${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.war"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 783,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2018-05-15T08:55:51.049068973Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "Health": {
                "Status": "starting",
                "FailingStreak": 2,
                "Log": [
                    {
                        "Start": "2018-05-15T09:00:51.049533205Z",
                        "End": "2018-05-15T09:00:51.197542821Z",
                        "ExitCode": -1,
                        "Output": "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"[ \\\\\\\"CMD-SHELL\\\\\\\"\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2018-05-15T09:05:51.202360089Z",
                        "End": "2018-05-15T09:05:51.296293315Z",
                        "ExitCode": -1,
                        "Output": "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"[ \\\\\\\"CMD-SHELL\\\\\\\"\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Image": "sha256:72cafeeceda0db9170eebb0992c98afaaaf7d2f744a328bd8ceb18804ea0c941",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8f14979ae4eb4e16ec26a4ac886d29b29f5666e5f00d41c56d25f5efe0c7d57e/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8f14979ae4eb4e16ec26a4ac886d29b29f5666e5f00d41c56d25f5efe0c7d57e/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8f14979ae4eb4e16ec26a4ac886d29b29f5666e5f00d41c56d25f5efe0c7d57e/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8f14979ae4eb4e16ec26a4ac886d29b29f5666e5f00d41c56d25f5efe0c7d57e/8f14979ae4eb4e16ec26a4ac886d29b29f5666e5f00d41c56d25f5efe0c7d57e-json.log",
        "Name": "/ecs-hit-backend-task-21-hit-backend-container-f0afe6f9a694b6fcfb01",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "devicemapper",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "443"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 2,
            "Memory": 1073741824,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "/ecs/4c81e8c4-de44-4c20-ab37-f8360b8ce639",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 2147483648,
            "MemorySwappiness": 0,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": [
                {
                    "Name": "nofile",
                    "Hard": 4096,
                    "Soft": 1024
                }
            ],
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "DeviceId": "4392",
                "DeviceName": "docker-202:1-263287-a309a6780a0a4e0f2da29705109433ba9be5b7a602e4198b42a83e84e8aa8cc8",
                "DeviceSize": "10737418240"
            },
            "Name": "devicemapper"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "8f14979ae4eb",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8080/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre",
                "JAVA_VERSION=8u151",
                "JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION=8.151.12-r0",
                "SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=ALWAYS",
                "JHIPSTER_SLEEP=0",
                "JAVA_OPTS="
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "echo \"The application will start in ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}s...\" &&     sleep ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP} &&     java ${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.war"
            ],
            "Healthcheck": {
                "Test": [
                    "CMD",
                    "[ \"CMD-SHELL\"",
                    "\"echo\""]"
                ],
                "Interval": 300000000000,
                "Timeout": 60000000000,
                "StartPeriod": 300000000000,
                "Retries": 10
            },
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "401402660647.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/hit_backend:b6f196e.dirty",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.amazonaws.ecs.cluster": "hit-ecs-cluster",
                "com.amazonaws.ecs.container-name": "hit-backend-container",
                "com.amazonaws.ecs.task-arn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:401402660647:task/4c81e8c4-de44-4c20-ab37-f8360b8ce639",
                "com.amazonaws.ecs.task-definition-family": "hit-backend-task",
                "com.amazonaws.ecs.task-definition-version": "21"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "e3d450f7592c56382d6103b310f2c45c87877c078cd489a897be6ddc45ff77dc",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "443"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/e3d450f7592c",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "200429fb30b4ea42dd9bd5250a70675435b4020859ef8c98ec60dac31398b83d",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "a1f7250c4c4be44b8f10385be14d47049418967f7cccaa322852daf0954cae73",
                    "EndpointID": "200429fb30b4ea42dd9bd5250a70675435b4020859ef8c98ec60dac31398b83d",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

What seems to be the problem is the following line:

```
"Health": {
                "Status": "starting",
                "FailingStreak": 2,
                "Log": [
                    {
                        "Start": "2018-05-15T09:00:51.049533205Z",
                        "End": "2018-05-15T09:00:51.197542821Z",
                        "ExitCode": -1,
                        "Output": "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"[ \\\\\\\"CMD-SHELL\\\\\\\"\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2018-05-15T09:05:51.202360089Z",
                        "End": "2018-05-15T09:05:51.296293315Z",
                        "ExitCode": -1,
                        "Output": "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"[ \\\\\\\"CMD-SHELL\\\\\\\"\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

I have tried various configurations of the healthcheck (CMD instead of CMD-SHELL, /bin/sh, just "echo" etc.) nothing seems to work.

What is the minimal always true healthcheck for Amazon ECS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it seems the documentation on AWS is extremely misleading.
When using the ECS portal one should type only comma delimited commands, i.e.:

echo,hello world

Comment: Thank you. Spent a good 6 hours yelling at my computer trying to figure this out. How would you express `CMD python /app/healthcheck.py || exit 1`? Specifically, how do I express the `|| exit 1` part? Or is this not needed?

Comment: If possible, I would change the /app/healthcheck.py to return 0 status on success, or 1 status on failure, using sys.exit(status).  Would also like to thank norbitheeviljester,  been running around in circles for hours with this one.

Answer (score 2):

I also found the docs misleading. 
Here's a couple of healthchecks that worked for me:

```
CMD,curl,--fail,http://localhost:80/status.php
```

[image: curl localhost]

or

```
CMD-SHELL,SCRIPT_NAME=status.php,SCRIPT_FILENAME=/var/www/html/status.php,REQUEST_METHOD=GET,cgi-fcgi,-bind,-connect,localhost:9000
```

[image: cgi-fcgi php status]

And you can dig into what's happening on the instance with:

```
docker inspect 284ce427a3fd --format='{{json .Config.Healthcheck}}' | jq
docker inspect 284ce427a3fd --format='{{json .State.Health}}' | jq
```

Comment: use kubernetes :)

Comment: Might be obvious, but could save someone some debugging time: make sure your container has curl included. E.g. alpine images do not by default.

Comment: @MarttiLaine Or use `wget` instead of `curl` so you don't have to install another dependency: `curl --fail -s http://localhost/something` -> `wget -qO- http://localhost/something`

Comment: THANK YOU @MarttiLaine that was exactly why my service hasn't been working for the last few days